# Setting indexes using a TextField

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have two models (tables) in my database, let's call them `Model1` and `Model2`.

The first one contains some information about features. We can imagine that there are two TextFields. First `name_id` is unique for each feature and the second one `data` contains some information. It would look like this

```
row1: name_id=feature1, param='Fixed'  
row2: name_id=feature2, param='On going'
```

The second model also has two field. The first one is called `features`. It is a TextField with features separated by commas (with or without spaces) or semicolons. Another field is also a TextField and stores some additional information. For example some rows might look as follows

```
row1: features=feature1, feature2, feature3, info=1
row2: features=feature1;feature2;feature3, info=2
row3: features=feature1,feature2,feature3, info=3
row4: features=feature1, info=4
```

In the real world both tables are huge (millions of instances).

I would like to iterate over features from `Model1` and grab data from the `info` field in `Model2`. I would like to make this process memory efficient thus I need and index on the field `features` in `Model2`.

I suppose I would need a regex function and the index function. How could it be done?

Comment: What about a proper data model? That would fix your problem. This is exactly why database normalisation is done

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be done easily. That field is used throughout huge amount of legacy code.

Comment: What kind of queries or conditions do you need to support with that index? Can you [edit] your question and add some sample conditions (or queries)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I changes my post. Now it should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but you can do that if you convert the column to an array and search in that, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE regexp_split_to_array(features, ', *') @> ARRAY['feature3'];
```

Then you can use a GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin (regexp_split_to_array(features, ', *'));
```

But since you don't want to change your legacy code, you probably also cannot change your queries...